# jQuery, Passing object on click from array to another function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of objects coming into my web page. One property of the object is firstName. I display some of the properties and have a clickable one that calls another fuction. I want to pass the object from the array to the second function

```
jQuery.each(x, function () {
            $('#results').append("<a href='javascript:void(0)' onClick='workSup(" + '"' + $(this) + '"' + ")' >" + decodeURI(this.firstName) + ' ' + decodeURI(this.lastName) + " - " + decodeURI(this.preApprovalSupervisorName) + " <a/><br/> ");
        });

 function workSup(x) {

        alert(x.firstName);
    }
```

I've tried passing this as well as $(this). The alert reads "undefined"

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Your creating a inline binding.  That bind value is going to be a string, not directly referencing any objects.  Rather than performing an inline binding, create the `a` element and then either create the `onclick` on it or use the `addEventListener` to create the event binding on it

Comment: My version: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/rL5o124a/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery has a great function, .data(), I'd recommend you look into:

```
$('#selector').data("key", "value (string, number, object, etc.)")
$('#selector').data("key");  //Returns the data, or null if not yet set
```

Also, I highly recommend moving away from onclick to

```
$('.myClassName').on("eventName (such as click, change or keyup)", "jqSelector", handlerFunction);
```

```js
var x = [{firstName:"John", lastName:"Lennon"}, {firstName:"Phil", lastName:"Ochs"}]

$(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery.each(x, function () {
      var linkEl = $('<a class="myLink" href="javascript:void(0)">' + this.firstName + " " + this.lastName + '</a>');
      linkEl.data("myObjData", this);
      $('#results').append(linkEl);
  });
  $(document).on("click", ".myLink", function() {
       var myObjData = $(this).data("myObjData");
       //myObjData.firstName can be accessed here
       alert(JSON.stringify(myObjData));
  });
});
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="results"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

$('.myClass').on() is even better than $('.myClass').click() because it will even listen to elements that are dynamically added later

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery.each(x, function() {
  //create the a element
  var $a = $("<a href='javascript:void(0)'>"+
                 decodeURI(this.firstName) +' '+ decodeURI(this.lastName) +
                 " - "+ decodeURI(this.preApprovalSupervisorName) +
             "</a><br/>");

  //bind the event handler to it
  $a.on('click', function(){
      workSup(x);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @taplar you're creating inline binding. Basically what happens is that your `$(this)` gets resolved as string and later inside your `workSup()` method you're trying to access `firstName` property of the string which is obviously undefined.

What you have to do instead is to dynamically create your link and attach event listener to it (in which you call the `workSup()` method) like so:

```js
// Your data
const x = [
  { firstName: 'First', lastName: 'Last', preApprovalSupervisorName: 'Super' },
  { firstName: 'Another', lastName: 'One', preApprovalSupervisorName: 'His super' },
];

// Your workSup method
const workSup = x => alert(x.firstName);

// Loop though each item
$.each(x, function() {
  // Create new <a> element
  const $element = $('<a></a>')
    // Add href attribute
    .attr('href', 'javascript:void(0)')
    // Set its text
    .text(`${decodeURI(this.firstName)} ${decodeURI(this.lastName)} ${decodeURI(this.preApprovalSupervisorName)}`)
    // Attach onClick listener
    .on('click', () => workSup(this));
  
  // Append the element to the results and add line break
  $('#results')
    .append($element)
    .append('<br />');
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="results"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var x =[{firstName: "John", lastName:"DG", preApprovalSupervisorName: "sup"}];

jQuery.each(x, function (index, value) {
            $('#results').append(
            $("<a>")
             .attr("href","#")
             .html( decodeURI(value.firstName) + ' ' + decodeURI(value.lastName) + " - " + decodeURI(value.preApprovalSupervisorName))
              .click(function(){
              workSup(value);
              
              })
            );
        });

 function workSup(x) {

        alert(x.firstName);
    }
```